# Show that if $f=g\ \text{a.e.}$ on $[a,b]$ implies that $f=g$ on $[a,b]$.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose that $f,g$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$. Show that if $f=g\ \text{a.e.}$ on $[a,b]$ then in fact $f=g$ on $[a,b]$.

Is the result true if $[a,b]$ is replaced by any measurable set?

**My effort**:

Let $A=\{x\in [a,b]:f(x)\neq g(x)\}$. It is given that $\mu(A)=0$ where $\mu$ denotes measure of a set.

To show that $A=\emptyset$. Suppose that $A\neq \emptyset $. Let $p\in A$. Then $f(p)\neq g(p)$ and also $f,g$ are continuous at $p$.

As $\mu(A)=0$ then there exists a sequence of intervals $\{I_n\}$ such that $A\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n)<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

But I am unable to use the continuity of $f,g$. Please give some hints.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ are distinct.

Then there is an $x_0\in [a,b]$ with $f(x_0)\neq g(x_0)$

By continuity there is  $\delta>0$ so that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for all $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\cap[a,b]$.

This set has measure larger than $0$, so we conclude $f$ and $g$ are not equal almost everywhere.

---

If we change $[a,b]$ with any other measurable set the result may not hold, for example $\{0\}$ is a measurable set (it's measure is zero).

If $f,g$ are any two functions from $\{0\}$ to $\mathbb R$ , then $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and clearly $f=g$ a.e. But of course $f$ must not be equal to $g$ necessarily.

Comment: I said [a,b] ;I fail to extract anything from your answer.Did you read the question and most importantly my effort

Comment: You asked if the result is true if you replace $[a,b]$ with any measurable set, it is false.

Comment: I added a proof for when the set is $[a,b]$. There are some small "gaps", but you should be able to fill them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer;It is clear now

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Maybe I misunderstood (apologies for commenting on a solution from 2016), but don't you mean to say, "By the continuity there is a $\delta>0$ so that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for all $x\in(x_{0}-\delta, x_{0}+\delta)\cap [a,b]$?" In any case, elegant solution. The counterexample I used (conceptually similar) is $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\neq g$ on some subset $S\subset\mathbb{Z}$, but $f,g$ are equal at all points not in $S$ -- both functions are continuous that are equal a.e., yet are not equal on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out @Procore

Comment: @Procore I'm sorry to comment on 2020. For your counterexample, why $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $\mathbb{Z}$? If I'm mistaken, please tell me more details. Thanks.

Comment: @himath If $F:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function, then $F$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., $F$ is continuous at any integer). //Proof: Fix any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ arbitrarily, and then let $\varepsilon>0$. 'Choosing' $\delta\in(0,1)$, e.g. $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$, then the only 'integer' in the set $(k-\delta,k+\delta)$ is $k$ itself -- in other words, if $x\in(k-\delta,k+\delta)\cap\mathbb{Z}$ then $x=k$. Overall, this implies $\big|F(k)-F(x)\big|=|F(k)-F(k)\big|=0<\varepsilon$ concluding $F$ is continuous at $k$. As $k$ was arbitrary, $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @himath Recalling when asked to provide a counterexample, I went to the notion that any countable set of reals is measurable and has (outer-) measure zero. I thought this since two, distinct, measurable functions can achieve different values on a countable subset (which can be moderately large in 'size' even, especially if the subset is countably infinite) of the common domain, but because this subset has measure zero, the functions can $still$ be equal a.e. Remembering a real-valued function having the integers as its domain is continuous, the counterexample was a straight shot from there.

Answer (score 4):

We assume $f$ and $g$ are equal a.e. on $[a,b]$ with the set $A=\{x \in [a,b]|f(x)\neq g(x) \}$ and $m(A)=0$. We wish to show that $A$ is empty. Since the text only defines continuous **real-valued** functions we will assume $f$ and $g$ only take on real values so $f-g=0$ on $[a,b] \setminus A$. Next $f$ and $g$ are both continuous so $f-g$ is continuous. Thus we know that for any arbitrary $x \in [a,b]$, $f-g$ is  continuous. By definition of continuous at a point $x \in [a,b]$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $x' \in [a,b]$ and $|x-x'|<\delta$ then $|(f(x)-g(x)) - (f(x')-g(x'))|<\epsilon$. If we restrict $\delta<b-a$ then  $|x-x'|<\delta$ defines the interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta) \cap [a,b]$ such that $m((x-\delta,x+\delta) \cap [a,b])\geq \delta$.

The interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta) \cap [a,b]$ will contain points in $[a,b] \setminus A$ because its measure is greater than the measure of $A$. If we let $x'$ be an arbitrary point in $(x-\delta,x+\delta) \cap ([a,b]\setminus A)$ we know that
$$|(f(x)-g(x)) - (f(x')-g(x'))|<\epsilon$$
$$|(f(x)-g(x)) - 0)|<\epsilon$$
$$|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary this implies that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in A$ resulting in $f=g$ on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 3):

The function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is also continuous. Let $U=\{x: f(x)=g(x)\}.$

Then $U=h^{-1}\{0\}.$ So $U$ is closed.

Also, $U$ is  dense in $[a,b].$ Otherwise some open interval $(c,d)\subset [a,b],$ with $c<d,$ is disjoint from $U.$ But then $\mu (A)\geq d-c>0,$ where $A=\{x\in [a,b]: f(x)\ne g(x)\}.$

A closed dense subset of $[a,b]$ must equal $[a,b].$ So $U=[a,b].$

Answer (score 2):

Replacing $[a, b]$ by another measurable set won't work - consider the set $X = [0, 1] \cup \{2\}$. Say $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ and $g$ is the characteristic function of $\{2\}$. Then $f = g$ on $[0, 1]$, and hence almost everywhere on $X$; but $f \neq g$.

The key part of the proof you're looking for will have to do with the fact that nearby points will have nearby $f$-values (and likewise with $g$); if I were you, I'd try to prove that if $f(x) \neq g(x)$ then there is an entire interval around $x$ on which $f \neq g$.

Comment: However, the example you gave is not continuous, we need continuous functions here.

Comment: @Nan The example I gave is certainly continuous - on $X$, not on $\mathbb{R}$. Recall that a continuous function is a function so that the preimage of any open set is open. $g$ isn't a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ because, for example, $g^{-1}(0.9, 1.1)$ is $\{2\}$, which is not open; however, $\{2\}$ *is* open in the subspace topology on $X$.

Comment: Sorry about that, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose that $ f,g$  are continuous functions on $[a,b]$.  Show that
> if $f=g $ a.e. on $[a,b] $ then in fact $ f=g$ on $ [a,b]$

$A=\{x\in [a,b]:f(x)\neq g(x)\}$

> Theorem: $(X, \tau) $ and $(Y, \tau') $ be two topological space and
> $(Y, \tau') $ is Hausdorff. $f, g $ two continuous functions .
>
> Then $\{x\in X :f(x) =g(x) \}$ is a closed set in $X$.

From the above theorem it follows that $A$ is an open set in $[a, b]$.

Claim :$A=\emptyset$

Asaume the contrary, $x_0\in A$

Then, $\exists \delta>0$ such that

$(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)\subset A $

Now, by monotonicity of measure,

$m((x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta))\le m(A )$

Hence, $m(A) \ge 2\delta>0$

Contradiction!

2nd part:

Choose, $\Bbb{Z}\cup\{\frac{1}{2}\}$

Consider, $f(x) =\sin(\pi x) $

Then, $f(x)=0$ a.e on $\Bbb{Z}\cup\{\frac{1}{2}\}$

But $f \neq 0 $ on $\Bbb{Z}\cup\{\frac{1}{2}\}$