# $f, g$ are continuous functions on $E$ where $E$ is measurable set. If $f=g$ a.e on $E$ then $f=g$ on $E$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

**problem**

> $f, g$ are continuous functions on $E$ where $E$ is Lebesgue measurable set. If $f=g$ a.e on $E$ then $f=g$ on $E$? If not, give a counterexample.

**effort**

> Let us change $[a,b]$ with $\{0\}$ which is a measurable set. Let $f: \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions. Then, $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and clearly $f=g$ a.e. But of course $f$ must not be equal to $g$ necessarily.

**question**

1. Is the example proper?
2. Could you tell me more details?

**refer**

[Show that if $f=g \text{a.e}$ on $[a,b]$ implies that $f=g$ on $[a,b]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876516/738484)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get your example with $\mathbb{Z}$. The question clearly states that $f=g$ on a measurable set. How can you take $f\neq g$ on $S$? $S$ is measurable.

Comment: What measure are you assuming for $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: I concur with the above two comments.  Also, if you are trying to take an example where the measure of $E$ is zero, what about taking $E = \{0\}$?

Comment: What measure are you using for $\mathbb{Z}$? The counting measure? In that case If $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ then $S$ has positive measure so they aren't equal a.e. and your example doesn't contradict the claim.

Comment: I'm sorry to embarrass everyone. First, I use Lebesgue measure. Second, I tried to use $\{0\}$ which is measure is $0$. Third, I've corrected your question, so please check it out. Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you're using Lebesgue measure, then $\mathbb Z$ itself has zero measure, so $f$ and $g$ can disagree everywhere and still be equal almost everywhere.

Comment: @Bungo I figure out that If I take $f(0)=1 \neq 2 =g(0)$, the problem is solved! Thanks!

Comment: At a high level: You start out your effort by saying "Let us change $[a,b]$..." but nothing has ever been said about $a$ or $b$.  So at the start it is confusing. It is like starting out "let us assume the mountain is purple..." (what mountain?)

Comment: @Michael Thank you for telling me the details! I'll take it into account and revise it. I think that it is good: Consider $\{0\}$ which is a measurable set. Thanks!